# (Responsive design) Div disappears when I add flex-direction: column to parent div - what is wrong?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

This is the HTML code for the relevant elements:

```
<div class="data">
<div class="dataispod">
<div class = "detaljilevo">
    <div class="detaljilevosub">
        [...]
    </div>

    <div id="buttonwrapperdetalji">
        [...]
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slikacontainer">
    <div class="slikawrap" style="background-image: url('../slike/<?=$podaci->slika?>')"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS code for the relevant components:

```
.data {
    margin: 80px 60px 0px 80px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 400px;
    width: 70%;
}

.dataispod {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}

.slikacontainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
}

.slikawrap {
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

.data {
        margin: 20px 60px 30px 60px;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        max-height: 1000px;
        min-width: 50%;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .dataispod {
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 500px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the image div fully disappears when I add `flex-direction: column` to the `data` class, so I cannot even start editing the width and other elements to fit it to be responsive because I cannot find it. The responsiveness of other elements works perfectly fine. Can someone help me out?

Comment: you don't have an image element inside of `.slikawrap` you are using a background image, sort that out and then it should work, you mgiht want to set `background-size: cover;` in your css of the `.slikawrap` class

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Thank you for the reply. Yes, I'm aware of that. I just realized that was leftover code from when I was trying to use an image, I've updated the question without it. It's still not showing up at all when I try to go below a certain width, I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the image has no height, and in `flex-direction: row;` it's taking the height of other elements, but for `flex-direction: column;` it has no height. Try adding the following in `.slikawrap` to see if that's the case.

```
min-height: 40px;
```

Also prefer using `background` property instead of separate `background-size`, `background-repeat`, `background-position`.

```
.slikawrap {
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 40px;
  background: url('') center contain no-repeat;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
}
```